# Visual Studio cannot delete EXE file during build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a project that I have been working on for a few weeks using Visual Studio 2017. I created a "release" build which worked fine. I then need to make some changes and create a second "release" build.

This time the build failed as it did not have permission to overwrite the EXE file created in the first build The machine I am running is a personal machine with only me as the admin user. Studio clearly had permissions the first time why would it not have permissions the second time?

For the "debug" build I can rebuild as many times as I want.

Any thoughts as to what the issue may be?

Comment: I remember having this problem in the past too, annoying as hell.  1. Try running visual studio as administrator to verify that the problem is indeed permissions.  2.  Look at the security of the output folders where the release intermediates and output files are being created.

Comment: Ensure you enable _Visual Studio Hosting Process_ in **Debug** settings

Comment: In my experience, in most cases, my program was actually running. I normally use Task Manager and check whether any instance of my program is still running and then kill them all. Then do a project build

Comment: I've experienced this quite a bit and haven't found a solution. Best guess is that there is a delay in some component of VS 2017 releasing a handle on the resource. Sadly, I'm now in the habit of building twice.

Comment: I am having this problem but the exe does NOT appear in my task manager.  Any idea what that could be?

Comment: I have the same problem in VS2022 with debug build. Had to restart my PC at least 10 times yesterday. I made zero progress yesterday

Answer (score -2):

The .exe program you are trying to delete may be running in the background. Just reboot your pc.

Comment: What a great solution. /s

Comment: While this is a sure fire fix, it is not an optimal solution.  You might need to reboot a dozen times in a day and that should not be necessary.